# TinyMCE gulp configuration

Tags: javascript, node.js, tinymce, gulp, browserify

I am building a web application and I want to use TinyMCE. I am using gulp and browserify. I have downloaded TinyMCE through npm and than I have required it in my app.js file and run the `gulp` command but I got this error `Failed to load: root/js/themes/modern/theme.js`. I think this is because TinyMCE needs additional files from its folder. My question is how to configurate TinyMCE to search those files in the node_modules/tinymce folder.

Comment: When do you have this error? Is when you attempt to load in browser?

Comment: I have some error after concat and uglify. So, I added theme.js fail to concat and then rewrite css paths in theme.js.

Answer (score 4):

I had an open issue with the `main-bower-files` author who discouraged the use of it together with TinyMCE, probably due to the large number of extra files that must be included (?). See the following [issue](https://github.com/ck86/main-bower-files/issues/153) on Github.

I ended up just copying the tinymce folder to my `dist/` through a simple gulp task. I use Bower and different paths probably, but you get the idea

```
gulp.task('bower-tinymce', function() {

    //Copy resources from tinymce-dist that didn't make it in the bower-files
    return gulp.src('src/main/resources/static/bower_components/tinymce-dist/**/*').pipe(gulp.dest('src/main/resources/static/dist/tinymce'));

});
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer here depends completely on how you are packaging up files in your Gulp build. I'm still working through the same problem right now, but here's a tip that might help.

In my case, I'm using the [main-bower-files](https://www.npmjs.com/package/main-bower-files) plugin to read my Bower config and then return a stream of all the main JS files from all of my dependencies I've installed with Bower. It looks like this:

```
var mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');

gulp.task('vendor-src', function () {
  return gulp.src(mainBowerFiles('**/*.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(concat('main.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
});
```

Unfortunately, this does not pick up any of the TinyMCE files, which are installed in my bower_components directory, because the 'tinymce' installed through Bower does not come with a package.json file. I think this is because you have the choice between using the regular and jQuery versions of TinyMCE, which are both in the package.

I had to change my Gulp task from above to get it to pick up the TinyMCE source code that I want (the jQuery version). That version looks like this:

```
var mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');

gulp.task('vendor-src', function () {
  return gulp.src(
    mainBowerFiles('**/*.js', {
      "overrides": {
          "tinymce": {
            "main": ["tinymce.jquery.js", "plugins/**/*.js", "themes/**/*.js"]
          }
       })
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(concat('main.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
});
```

That will include all of the JS files associated with TinyMCE and add them to the "main bower files" list.

This is only a partial solution though because you also have to pick up the TinyMCE CSS and font files. And then if you're build is completely different or you're not using the main-bower-files plugin, this might not help either.