# What is the best way to manage js packages/files in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel

**First case:** i've got some script, which i've writed by myself(lets call it requests.js).

**Second case:** there is a big plugin TinyMCE, which i can install from bower or npm.

In first case as far as i understand, i should save my scripts in resources/assets/js. But where should i call them after this? There are 2 files in assets/js, which were installed with Laravel 5.3: app.js and bootstrap.js. Should i call my scripts in these files and then gulp them into a single one?

In second case i should use some npm or bower package manager. But, what should i do next? Where should i call this installed packages?In assets/js/ - app.js or bootstrap.js? But how, or maybe i shouldn't do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to put bower components in resource/assets/js only, because these components often consist of many files, js/css/others. I just use bower install inside root of the installation, bower_components dir appears and I put it into .gitignore. Anyone who pulls changes, can do bower install.

Going further, I make file, where I create json object with two values, js and css, where I put path to files I need. Then I require it inside gulp.js and I can do whatever I want with these files. Usually concat, minify, copy result to public.

Theres nothing wrong with putting frontend into same server. Maybe you work alone or in the small team, and you don't have time to manage too many things. Common practice I see all around is that people make dir angular inside root and just grab all js/html files inside this dir, and copy them to public inside gulp.

Comment: Thx for this answer! Will it be **OKAY** if i will do smth like this: for example, i've installed via bower or npm some **package**, which consists of sass styles and some javascript. After this i will import **styles** from this package into **main** sass file. **Scripts** from this package i will include in gulp file and will concatenate it with **other** scripts from another packages or scripts done by myself. So?

Comment: You can do it, It would be 3 step operation, concat vendor styles, build your styles, concat your styles with vendor. I like to keep four separate css/js files. Mine css/js and vendor css/js. 

And with sass it will be even easier, you don't have to concat vendor, everything will work at once. For example laravel by default included(don't know how it is in current version) bootstrap sass files in app.scss . Just keep an eye on path ./   ;)

Comment: And the last question to specify some things: i've installed bower and installed a package. Then in gulp.js file i should call scripts from this package, smth like this  `.scripts(['/bower_components/etc'
       ], './public/js/etc');`, . But it won't work: i need to do smth like `../../../bower_components/etc`, because elixir uses `resources/assets/js` as default folder for assets. I'm i doing smth wrong or it's proper way to do it?

Comment: remember to keep an eye on path ?     
`mix.scripts(['./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', next one], 'public/js/vendor.js');`  gulp file is in the root, so do bower components, no need to configure anything

Comment: And the very last one: there is a big plugin, which consists not only from a single script. This plugin works only when it is situated in public directory(in this case public/js directory). So i tried to do smth like this:        `mix.scripts(['./bower_components/tinymce/tinymce.min.js']);`. But the thing is that this plugin works only if i will call it smth like this `<script src="/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>`, and `<script src="/js/all.js"></script>`, won't work(this one contains scripts from gulp file) . I've copied this entire package into public directory, but it didnt help.

Comment: also had such problem with tinymce, script calls others from inside, probably I would add all js files from tinymce folder directly, maybe with 'bowr/tinymce/**/*.js , but I left this problem by calling tinymce from cdn <script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script> . There were some trials http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467943/tinymce-gulp-configuration

Answer (score 1):

It's opinion based, but I think it is not a good practice to mix front-end and back-end.

## Your Proposal

Your public (front-end) files, like bootstrap, you should store them in `public/` of the Laravel installation. You can use `public/assets/js`, etc. The folder `resources` is not available in your html files (if you mean the folder of your Laravel installation).

## Better Approach

A better approach is to `separate totally` your front-end from back-end. In that case, you need a front-end framework, like AngularJS or Ember.

Why?

- You can `replace` one of them `without troubles` in the other
- You can use your back-end as `third party api` (https://api.yourdomein.com/v1/...)
- `No conflicts` with blade views and other template formats
- Of course, `separation of responsibilities`

Answer (score 1):

You should install your bower components in your `resources/assets/js` folder. Then add any of these components to your build process in your gulpfile. This way, you have total control over what gets concatenated and minified and ultimately included in your templates.

Comment: so i should have a folder "bower_components" in 'resources/assets/js', or in some file('app.js' for example) i should call this bower components and then gulp them?

Comment: Yes, `resources/assets/js/bower_components` -- then add the js files from that to your `gulpfile.js` -- concat them, minify them, version them... whatever. Then include the output file(s) in your templates.